# How to rewrite virtual subdomain to query parameter with other parameters using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am creating subdomain for all users in my website. I used wildcard subdomain and handling it with htaccess file with following code. This is working fine. It rewrites user1.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/subdir/index.php?user=user1

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ subdir/index.php?user=%1 [L]
```

Now, I need to add one more parameter to the url. Please suggest.

How to rewrite
user1.mydomain.com?data=value1 to mydomain.com/subdir/index.php?user=user1&data=value1

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: You should learn to differ between "rewriting" and "redirecting". What you address above is _rewriting_ and _not_ redirecting.

Comment: @CBroe QSA Flag worked. :) Please add it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying your own query string in the substitution URL, will by default discard any query string that existed on the original URL.

The [`QSA` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) allows you to specify that you want your new query string, and the one from the originally requested URL, to be merged.